# Getting -858993460 as a result c++

Tags: c++

The program send me -858993460 value on a[ch] an b[nech] why ?? i cant understand that ... if i use `cout<<m[i]` on place of `cout<<a[ch]<<endl;` it works fine ... shows me the even and odds but when i try to send them to another array the value goes wrong ( I need those another two arrays a[ch] and b[nech])

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main()

 {
int i,n;
int m[3], a[3]={0}, b[3]={0};
int ch=0, nech=0;
for(i=0; i<3; ++i)
{
    cout<<i+1<<". Studenski fark. nomer: ";
    do
    {
        cin>>m[i];
    }
    while(!(m[i]>=1e7 && m[i]<1e8));
    if(m[i]%2==0)
    {
        m[i]==a[ch]; ch++;
        //cout<<m[i]<<endl; "without the down 'fors' it works"
    }
    else 
    {
        m[i]==b[nech]; nech++;
        //cout<<m[i]<<endl; "without the down 'fors' it works"
    }
}
cout<<"\nVsichki fakultetni nomera: "<<endl;
for(i=0; i<3; ++i)
cout<<m[i]<<"\t";
cout<<"Chetni fark nomera: \n";
if(ch!=0)
    for(i=0;i<ch;i++)
        cout<<a[ch]<<"\t"; //"with {0} on 'a' I receive 0 as result"
else 
    cout<<"nqma chetni fak nomera";
if(nech!=0)
    for(i=0;i<nech;i++)
        cout<<b[nech]<<"\t"; //"same here 0 as result with {b}"
else
    cout<<"Nqma nechetni fak nomera";

getch();
 }
```

Comment: It would help if you described what you're trying to achieve. What's `a[]` and `b[]` supposed to do?

Comment: The value is not a random one, is 0xcccccccc in hex, which in Visual Studio is an uninitialized int in debug mode.

Comment: -858993460 = 0xCCCCCCCC which means [you've accessed uninitialized memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/370195/995714)

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize your arrays

```
int m[3] = {0}
int a[3] = {0};
int b[3] = {0};
```

Without initializing the array, the value is random value from stack.

Comment: no it doesnt work.. now it shows me only 0 0 0 as a result ..

Comment: first you got value to `cin>>m[i];` but m[i] reset again by `m[i]=a[ch]; ch++;`

Comment: ok check the edited code ... it works fine in first for but when i try to use them down in the next for it gets the same ...

Comment: can you type me the full program with my code... i'm getting those 0 0 0 as result ... can't do my next check

Answer (score 1):

`m[i]=a[ch]` is undefined behavior because `a` is an array of uninitialized `int`s.

You're never reading into `a`. What would you expect the behavior to be?

Comment: in addition, with `m[i]=a[ch]; ch++; cout<<a[ch]<<endl;`, for i=2, `a[ch]` in `cout` statement will access the a[3] -> beyond array size...

Comment: how to unitialisite it ... when i try to set in the a[ch] b[nech] with ={0} result is 0 ...

Answer (score 0):

You're not initialising the elements of `a` and `b` anywhere, so they have pretty much random initial value (e.g. the -858993460 you're getting).